# Having trouble with syntax in swift looping through an array

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through this usernames array, but am not sure the syntax. I am using swift in xcode

I currently have:

```
 // Read text file
        if let filepath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("barbers", ofType: "txt")
        {
            do
            {
                //let contents = try NSString(contentsOfFile: filepath, usedEncoding: nil) as String;
                //print(contents);
                let text = try NSString(contentsOfFile: filepath, usedEncoding: nil) as String;

                // Create character array & parse
                let usernames = text.characters
                    .split { $0 == "\n" }
                    .map { String($0) }
                    .map { String($0.characters.split(" ")[0]) }

                // Print Users
                print(usernames);

                // Test



            }
            catch
            {
                // Catch error?
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Print error to console log
            print("Error: Could not find text file - something went wrong");
        }
```

My question is: How can I loop through my usernames array?

I just dont know the swift syntax

I'm looking for something like

```
for(int i =0; i < usernames.size(); i ++ )
{
  if(usernames[i] == USER)
  {
    b = true;
    break;
  }
  b = false;
}
```

> > **UPDATES:**

Ok so I've figured out how to loop through but now I'm having troubles

I made a global variable

```
var abc = "";
```

I then did

```
let abc = usernames;
```

now when I try to do this

```
// Test
for i in abc.characters
{
    print("abc array contents: " + i);
    if(i == theUser)
    {
        print("Barber");
        barb = true;
        break;
    }
    print("USER " + theUser);
    barb = false;
    print("\n");
}
```

I get the error

**Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Character'**

and

**Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Character' and 'String'**

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html that should help

Comment: kye right now im using this and its not working for some reason... But when i print out the contents of i it says what it should say but its like not even executing the body of my for loop for some reason... here is whati have     // Test
                for i in usernames
                {
                    print(i);
                    if(i == theUser)
                    {
                        print("Barber");
                        barb = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    barb = false;
                    
                }

Comment: Check out the answers provided, they all should work! Also could you update your question with that code (it's quite hard to read in comments)

Comment: If you just want to check if the usernames array contains a given string: `if usernames.contains(USER) { ... }`

Comment: Check out my updated post. I'm now running into a different problem trying to loop through the array

Comment: @Yusha in your for loop you iterate over the sequence of characters, so `i` variable is of character type, not of string type.

Comment: How can i fix this ?

Comment: because if i dont put the .characters then it says: Value of type 'String' has no member 'Generator'

Comment: @Yusha You're mutating your question... it started out on how to loop through an array's elements, now it's about how to print out a given element. You should only be asking one *specific* question per SO post. I would recommend leaving this question about looping through arrays – and asking a new question about your current problem (after ensuring that it's [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). That way it'll be much clearer for future readers, and you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these above work, but my favorite Swifty for loop is

```
  for index in 0..< usernames.count { 
     //your code here
     //to get an object at a specific index you call usernames[index]
  }
```

In response to your updated question I believe you need to cast your character as a string. Something like

```
  let myCharacterAsAString = String(i)
  print("abc array contents: " + myCharacterAsAString);
  if(myCharacterAsAString == theUser)
  {
    print("Barber");
    barb = true;
    break;
  }
  print("USER " + theUser);
  barb = false;
  print("\n");
}
```

Comment: How can I compare the strings in the username array to another string or textfield?

Comment: // Test
                for i in usernames
                {
                    print(i);
                    if(i == theUser)
                    {
                        print("Barber");
                        barb = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    barb = false;
                    
                }      this isnt working

Comment: Something like this if `(usernames[index] == inputString) {                                  //do this } else {                                                                                                        // do something else }`

Comment: Check out my updated post. I'm now running into a different problem trying to loop through the array

Comment: Your code compiled, but for some reason its not even going into my loops body

Comment: It's like not even going inside my for loop for some reason.. its almost like abc size is 0 or something its really weird

Comment: It's quite possible that it is size 0 if you did not set it up right. Check the size of abc via a breakpoint or a print statement

Answer (score 1):

```
for username in usernames
{
    if(username == USER)
    {
        b = true;
        break;
    }
    b = false;
}
```

or if you need access to current item's index:

```
for (index, username) in usernames.enumerate()
{
    // same body as above
}
```

Comment: how can i compare the username to another string ?

Comment: how can i also compare username to a textfield? for some reason this isnt working 
    // Test
                for i in usernames
                {
                    print(i);
                    if(i == theUser)
                    {
                        print("Barber");
                        barb = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    barb = false;
                    
                }

Comment: @Yusha comparing to another string is achieved simply by using equality operator (==). Updated the answer. To get text out of textField just access its 'text' property: `if(username == someTextField.text) {//... }`

Comment: Check out my updated post. I'm now running into a different problem trying to loop through the array

Answer (score 0):

I believe latest versions of Swift have done away with the C-style for-loop.
This might not be super helpful but the way to iterate in Swift would likely be with a for-in loop

```
for username in usernames
{
    if username == USER
    {
        b = true
        break
    }
    b = false
}
```

Comment: Check out my updated post. I'm now running into a different problem trying to loop through the array

Comment: @Yusha in swift you can't append a string to another string with +. in this case you could do `print("abc array contents: \(i)")`

As for your error on the `==` operator, you should probably compare objects of the same type like char == char. you can probably do `if i == theUser.characterAtIndex(0)` for your conditional if you're just expecting one character in `theUser`